# Should I override frameInit for initialization code in a Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing

I noticed that JFrame has a [`frameInit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#frameInit%28%29) method. I'm building a very simple GUI that extends JFrame. The description for the method is:

> Called by the constructors to init the JFrame properly.

If I have initialization code (such as setting the title, size, location, etc.), should I override the method, and put my initialization code in there? If not, where should I put initialization code (still assuming that I am extending JFrame, not using composition)?

Comment: *"I'm building a very simple GUI that extends JFrame."*  Don't extend frame.  That makes the rest of your question irrelevant.

Comment: @Bob example for [frameInit()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ExtendingJFrameClosingFramesbyDefault.htm)

Comment: @mKorbel: Excellent citation! Of course, one still needs a good reason to extend `JFrame`. Bob: I'm always grateful when Andrew reminds me not to extend `JFrame` unnecessarily.

Comment: @trashgod hmmm not good thread, in most cases I can't sensibile to filtering questions, I think OP's has really the interest to understand ..., but on seconds side I agreed with Andrew, commented this topic correctly,

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best place to put this stuff is in the constructor. Or, if you do overload, don't forget to call super.frameInit().